# Simple brute force troubleshoot

Tags: c++, brute-force

I need help fixing a very simple brute force attack on a set of numbers 1=9. My goal is to solve a sudoko board where a row is filled with 8 numbers so that there can only be one number left on the row. <del>The only way that I thought of to find this was to assign a number to the missing cell and then check it against every other number on the row. I'm really close to the solution but the return is always a 1. Here's the snippet of code that I'm having problems with:</del> I updated the code so that it now adds all the numbers and subtracts them from 45 to find the right number. It still doesn't return the right number. It returns 423 (With 6 as the missing number).

```
int radd1=deduct[0][0]+deduct[0][1]+deduct[0][2]+deduct[0][3]+deduct[0][4]+deduct[0] int test=0;
if (radd1==8) {
    for (int control=0; control<9; control++) {
        if (dash[0][control]=='_') {
            empty=control;
        }
    }
    for (int control2=0; control2<9; control2++) {
        if (control2!=empty) {
            test=test+dash[0][control2];
        }
    }
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

Some more info:
The entire solve is based off of one 9x9 char filled with numbers to go in their appropriate spots. This char is called `dash[9][9]`.
The `deduct[9][9]` char is a duplicate of `dash[9][9]` except that instead of the actual number that goes there, there is a `1`. This is so I can add up a whole row and if it is equal to `8` perform my simple brute force (if that's the right term) to find the final ninth number. `empty` is an int. It stores (in this case) the column number that has no number.
Spot any problems?

Comment: If `deduct` is 9×9, you have an error, you access `deduct[0][9]`, which very probably will read `deduct[1][0]`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually no it doesn't. The `FOR` loop initiates and runs through once at 0, and ends at 8 because I specified `control<9`

Comment: You have to take into account that you are using chars in the array and those can be used as integers but the char for '0' is not the same as the number 0. To recover the integer values you'd have to use `dash[0][control2]-'0'`.

Comment: @Redmastif the calculation of `radd1` used `deduct[0][9]` originally. I was referring to that.

Comment: @madth3 I actually changed `char dash[9][9]` to `int dash[9][9]` to fix another problem I was having.

Comment: What are you saving in the dash array? Something like `dash[i][j] = 1` or `dash[i][j] = '1'`? If it's the first then you could not obtain 423 by suming 8 numbers, if it's the second then my last comment still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a mistake to be using `deduct[0][9]` in the addition of radd1, right?
2. The comparison with `dash[0][control3]` is inside a cycle so that the value of test is always dependant in the last iteration of the cycle. (In this case `control2+1` vs `dash[0][8]`. I suppose you'd have to break the cycle if there is an equality.
3. You assign `control2+'1'` to `dash[0][empty]` but later use `control+1`. (Not the same thing)
4. The whole  assignment and comparison inside the condition `if (test==1)` doesn't feel right but we can't be sure if it's correct just from the included code.

There is a better way of finding the number that has not been used. We know the sum of `1+2+..+9 = 45`, so you'd only have to sum the appearing numbers and substract from 45 to obtain the number that's missing.